# Detect play event in youtube wrapped via MediaElement.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, youtube, mediaelement.js

I wrapped a youtube video into video tag via [MediaElement.js](http://johndyer.name/html5-video-wrapper-for-youtube-and-vimeo-api-mediaelement-js/):

```
<video id="v" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" type="video/youtube" >
</video>
```

It can be played correctly. I want to detect the play event (assume jQuery loaded):

```
$("#v").on('play', function() {
  console.log('play event entered');
  // do something more here
});
```

});

It seems the event can't be detected correctly. Is it because of the cross-origin issue? If so, theoretically I can build a proxy server for videos and then detect it correctly?

What I ultimately want to do is load the youtube clips into canvas. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing 'video' directly

```
$('video').on('play', function() {
     alert('playing');
 );
```

Comment: sorry, just noticed this does only work in chrome... :/ I'm trying to work out the same thing. I don't think it has to do with the source at all. I serve audio files from the local server only. Capturing any controls seems unreliable.

Comment: It doesn't work if the video is from a 3rd party site, even in chrome. Thanks anyway.